# Probability question involving three dice

Tags: probability, dice

Player $A$ rolls one die. Player $B$ rolls two dice. If $A$ rolls a number greater or equal to the largest number rolled by $B$, then $A$ wins, otherwise $B$ wins. What is the probability that $B$ wins?

I calculated the probability to be $$\frac 1 {36} + \frac 3 {36} \frac 5 6 + \frac 5  {36} \frac 4 6 + \frac 7 {36} \frac 3 6 + \frac 9 {36} \frac 2 6 + \frac {11} {36} \frac 1 6 = 1 -\frac {125} {216}$$

I then noticed that this is the same as $(5/6)^3$, and assumed that there might be a quicker way of obtaining this directly. Is this the case?

Comment: It should be $\frac{91}{216}$, not $\frac{125}{216}$.

Comment: The question asks for the probability that $B$ wins.  That is $125/216$.

Comment: ah, yes. I forgot to subtract it from 1. I'm still curious if there is a direct way of seeing that the answer is 1 - (5/6)^3

Comment: Read my answer below. It is a coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Sorry I didn't read carefully. You want the probability that $B$ wins, so it is indeed $\frac{125}{216}$, even though your equation gives $\frac{91}{216}$. Except for that, my analysis is correct. And yes you get your answer faster via $1-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^6 j^2}{216}=\frac{125}{216}$, but not from $\left(\frac 56\right)^3$.

---

Not sure how you arrived at $125$ since your equation gives $91$.

But, interestingly, $216-91=125$. Is it just a coincidence?

If Player $A$ throws a $j$, then there are $j^2$ cases that Player $B$ throws twice less than or equal to that, therefore the probability you want is $\frac{\sum_j j^2}{6^3} = \frac{91}{216}$, and you happen to have $6^3-\sum_{j=1}^6 j^2=125$. If you change 6 to some other integers you don't always get a perfect cube.

$3^3-\sum_{j=1}^3 j^2=13;$

$4^3-\sum_{j=1}^4 j^2=34;$

$5^3-\sum_{j=1}^3 j^2=70$, etc.

In general $n^3-\frac 16 n(n+1)(2n+1)=\frac 16 n(4n+1)(n-1)$ and you are lucky to have $4\cdot 6+1=25=(6-1)^2$.

(BTW if $n=14$ you get 1729, the [taxicab number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number).)

Answer (score 0):

The probability is given by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^6P[\max(B_1,B_2)>k\mid A=k]\cdot P[A=k]
=
\tfrac16\Bigl(\tfrac{35}{36}
+\tfrac{34}{36}
+\tfrac{27}{36}
+\tfrac{20}{36}
+\tfrac{11}{36}
+\tfrac{0}{36}\Bigr)
=\tfrac{127}{216}
\approx0.587963.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Three dice are rolled.  $A$ wins if his roll is the largest (or tied for largest).  There are three cases: (a) all three rolls are different, (b) two rolls are the same and the third is different, and (c) all three rolls are the same.  Case (a) can happen in $6\cdot 5\cdot 4$ ways, and $A$ wins with probability $1/3$ in that case.  Case (c) can happen in $6$ ways, and $A$ definitely wins in that case.  Finally, case (b) can happen in $6\cdot 5\cdot 3$ ways... in half of these, the pair is larger than the singleton, and $A$ wins with probability $2/3$; in the rest, the pair is smaller than the singleton, and $A$ wins with probability $1/3$... so overall, $A$ wins with probability $1/2$ in case (b).

The result is

$$
P_A=\frac{(6\cdot 5\cdot 4) \cdot \frac{1}{3}+(6\cdot 5\cdot 3)\cdot\frac{1}{2}+6}{6^3}=\frac{40+45+6}{6^3}=\frac{91}{216}.
$$